# Updated wordpress and my blog is displaying an error

Tags: php, wordpress, blogs

I'm new to wordpress, however I manged to install it and create a blog for a friend about a month ago. I updated word press an it's giving me this error:

http://blog.make-upbytalitha.com/

I'm certain all files are there.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because you have installed wordpress into the **wwwroot** instead of a **sub-directory**.  Wordpress by default assumes it will be installed in a sub-directory.

To solve this problem, modify the **index.php** file as follows if your WordPress installation is running in your root directory. You only need to change the following line:

```
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

To this:

```
require('wp-blog-header.php');
```

And then, everything should be working just fine.